# Jquery ajax toggling class

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have this page which let the user to decide yes or no. So I'm using Jquery Ajax so the user won't have to refresh his page. I have provided the button so the user may chose 'Yes' and immediately the button change to 'No'.

I represent '0' and '1' in mysql to indicate 'No' and 'Yes'. So when the user click the button, mysql will update the record '1' or '0'.

I managed to update the mysql by first click, but when come to second click, mysql won't take the order.

Here's my Jquery Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("document").ready(function()
                    {
                        $(".roundbox_blue").click(function()
                        {

                                $(this).toggleClass("roundbox_orange roundbox_blue");
                                var element = $(this);
                                var noteid = element.attr("value");
                                var info = "report="+noteid;


                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "mcr_external_gen.php",
                                    data: info,
                                    success: function(msg){

                                    }
                                });



                        });

                        $(".roundbox_orange").click(function()
                        {

                                $(this).toggleClass("roundbox_blue roundbox_orange");
                                var element = $(this);
                                var noteid = element.attr("value");
                                var info = "not_report="+noteid;


                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "mcr_external_gen.php",
                                    data: info,
                                    success: function(msg){

                                    }
                                });



                        });
                    });
            </script>
```

Then I have this code for the user to click:

```
<div class="show">
                <button class="roundbox_blue" value="1"> Click </button>
                <button class="roundbox_blue" value="2"> Click </button>
            </div>
```

The PHP code that will parse the AJAX query is like this:

```
    if(isset($_POST['report']))
{

    $line_id = $_POST['report'];

    $Portal->LoginDB('test');
    mysql_query('UPDATE `ajax` SET `report` = "1" WHERE `id`="'.$line_id.'"');



}
if(isset($_POST['not_report']))
{

    $line_id = $_POST['not_report'];

    $Portal->LoginDB('test');
    mysql_query('UPDATE `ajax` SET `report` = "0" WHERE `id`="'.$line_id.'"');



}
```

The problem I'm facing is, once the user click the button, mysql did update the record however, when the user click the button second time (meaning to cancel) mysql did not update the record accordingly.

I appreciate if you guys can help me out here..

Answer (score 0):

You are only hooking the blue box on doc load.

Answer (score 0):

change class of second button,

```
<div class="show">
                <button class="roundbox_blue" value="1"> Click </button>
                <button class="roundbox_orange" value="2"> Click </button>
            </div>
```